# Displaying data field in TexBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Select Value from ListBox.DataTextField and display result in TextBox1.text, -  VS VB ASP.NET Web Application - The app is to select a machine from a DropDownList which then shows a list of (possible) error codes in the Listbox(it's works so far) , when an error value is selected it shows the value description in the Textbox.text (this bit I can't get to work).

So far i have the following code, which works except for textbox1.text, I can load up the Dropdownlist then it shows the codes in the ListBox, But I can't get the fault description to display in the textbox..

data Tables are setup as follows in an .mdb file

2300Nc  |  2300Nr     |   2400Nc |  2400Nr     |   2500c   |  2500r  etc..

code| Fault Desc  |   code   | Fault Desc  |   code    `|  Fault Desc

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim MN = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text 'Takes the combobox item, i.e.'2300N and stores it as MN'
    Dim code As String
    Dim result As String

    code = MN & "c"                  ' Appends the letter c to the end of the sting (
    result = MN & "r"                ' The Code description.

    ListBox1.DataTextField = code    ' This bit works great.

    TextBox1.Text = "???????"        ' In VB I would use TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", mYBindingSource, result)

End Sub
```

I've bound the Data on the TextBox1 as below;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TC" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TroublecodesConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TroublecodesConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TC]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ModelNo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ModelConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ModelConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Model Number] AS Model_Number FROM [Table1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ModelNo" DataTextField="Model_Number" DataValueField="Model_Number">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="TC" Width="128px"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />

        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TC") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you want to do, but DropDownLists have an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply VDWWD,
The DropdownsList is not the problem, it's that I can't get the textbox to show the fault description 
EDIT: Edited OP to prevent any confusion about DropdownList.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but I don't have the ability to yet.  Have you tried:

```
TextBox1.Text = result
```